# firebase.firestore().collection().where(_, _, *) 'value' argument expected

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I've been working on React Native and Firebase project. All authentication and database have been using Firebase services. For some reason, after I implement a Loading state, I starting to receive this error message from the console.

## This is the React Native error

[image: React Native Console Error]

### This is my actual Chat component.

If I just commit the useEffects part, the project return to works.

```
const Chat = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const user = useSelector(({ auth }) => auth.user);
  const [unreads, setUnreads] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    firestore()
      .collection('threads')
      .where('users', 'array-contains', user?.uid)
      .orderBy('latestMessage.createdAt', 'desc')
      .onSnapshot(threadsSnapshot => {
        let count = 0;
        setUnreads(0);
        threadsSnapshot?.docs?.map(threadSnapshot => {
          firestore()
            .collection('threads')
            .doc(threadSnapshot.id)
            .collection('messages')
            .where('read', '==', false)
            .onSnapshot(messages => {
              messages.docs.map(message => {
                if (message.data().user._id !== user?.uid) {
                  count++;
                }
              });
              setUnreads(count);
            });
        });
      });
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Messenger')}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        style={style.menuContainerIcon}
        icon={faInbox}
        size={25}
        color="#14121E"
      />
      {unreads > 0 && (
        <Badge
          value={unreads > 99 ? '99+' : unreads}
          status="success"
          containerStyle={style.badgeMessages}
        />
      )}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const Header = ({
  setModalVisible,
  hideOptions,
  title,
  hideChat,
  hideFinder,
  hideBack,
}) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
      {!hideBack && (
        <IconButton icon="arrow-left" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
      )}
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
        <Text style={style.text}>{title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={style.menuContainer}>
        {!hideFinder && (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Messenger')}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              style={style.menuContainerIcon}
              icon={faSearch}
              size={20}
              color="#14121E"
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        {!hideOptions && (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              style={style.menuContainerIcon}
              icon={faEllipsisH}
              size={20}
              color="#14121E"
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        {!hideChat && <Chat />}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Does someone know what exactly arguments are expected by firebase function?

Answer (score 7):

You have two calls to `where()` here, but you didn't say which one the error was referring to.  I'm going to guess it's the first one:

```
.where('users', 'array-contains', user?.uid)
```

The third argument is going to be the "value" it's referring to.  I'm willing to bet that you're passing `undefined` here, and that `user` is undefined, which means that `user?.uid` is also undefined, which is not a valid value to pass to a Firestore query.  You'll have to debug why this value is not what you expect.  Maybe there is no user signed in at the time of this query.